# Firebase: How to set value to child without updating/deleting subChildren?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was trying to change values in child of my DB, but can't do it whithout deleting other data under this child. Trying to use push(), but it create new child and I want update value of existing child and save other childs.

[image]

Let's say I need to change ONLY value of Field 1 (email, name) and save child Test and other data under.

```
 databaseRef.child("Field 1").setValue(new UserForRealtimeDatabase("1st value of Field 1", "2st value of Field 1"));
```

This code is work but all the data under Field 1 complitely delete. 
Can you help me how to do that or may be there is no standart option for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do the following:

```
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Field 1");
Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<String,Object>();
updates.put("email", newemail);
updates.put("name", newname);

ref.updateChildren(updates);
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields

> `public Task<Void> updateChildren (Map<String, Object> update)`
>
> Update the specific child keys to the specified values. Passing null in a map to updateChildren() will remove the value at the specified location.

Comment: Thank you very much! You help me a lot! Can you make me a hint how can I check if the child exist before updating it?

Comment: Do if(dataSnapshot.exists(){ and then inside of it do the code above