# Firebase: How to update some fields out of many without deleting other keys/fields?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

After a few hours of research and reading several posts, I am still unclear on how I can achieve what I want. The closest I found was this: [Firebase: How to set value to child without updating/deleting subChildren?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49921426/firebase-how-to-set-value-to-child-without-updating-deleting-subchildren) but that didn't work for my need either.

My need is fairly simple. In the firebase RealTime DB, I am trying to use it for a 2 player game.

I create a "Game session" key on game start and inside that I add a few fields like player1, player2, start time:

```
 Map<String, Object> dbUpdates = new HashMap<>();
 dbUpdates.put("player1", player1Id);
 dbUpdates.put("player2", player2Id);
 dbUpdates.put("game_started", true);

 myRef.child("Games").child(game_session).updateChildren(dbUpdates);
```

[image]

Then when the first move is done, I want to **add** more key/values like move, nextmove, gameover status etc. to this same game session:

I do this by:

```
Map<String, Object> dbUpdates = new HashMap<>();
dbUpdates.put("nextMove", player1ID);
dbUpdates.put("move", "1,1");
dbUpdates.put("game_over", false);

myRef.child("Games").child(game_session).updateChildren(dbUpdates);
```

No my expectation is all the keys are available after the moves including the keys added during game start, but when the second **updateChilderen** is called, I lose the prev key-values and only end up with new key-values:

[image]

I can use **setValues() for each new key** added during the first move which means the listener will be fired 3 times and 3 fragmented updates will be pushed to DB, which I want to avoid. Any guidance is greatly appreciated, this is my first firebase realtime DB project, so apologies in advance if I am doing something really stupid.

Comment: Have a look at the doc: [Update specific fields](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields)

Comment: Thanks Renaud, I indeed read the article you pointed, but unfortunately couldn't really follow how it addresses  my use case. It talks about using updateChildren() which exactly is what I am doing.

Comment: Calling `updateChildren` only updates the keys that are present in the map you specify, and leaves other children unmodified. While it is always possible that a bug snuck into the product of course, it seems unlikely (given how relatively untouched this has been for quite some time now). Since you are seeing different behavior, I recommend looking for other code where you may still be calling `setValue()`.

Comment: Thanks Frank. I really hoped this to be true, but I reconfirm that the updateChildren() is indeed flushing the prev keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few hours of struggle, I came to conclusion that the above use case cannot be achieved in entirety in the way I am looking it to be.

Hence I implemented a little tweaked way which hopefully will help someone, someday with similar needs.

I added a sub-node **move** under the games session and now I do **updateChildren()** at the **move** node level. This way my game parameters like player1 and player2 info are intact and with every move I just update the /move children.

[image]